# MongoDB - textSearchEnabled - specify in config file

Tags: mongodb

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/

This doc says, we can specify this in the configuration file

> You can enable the text search feature at startup with the
>   textSearchEnabled parameter:
>
> **mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true**
>
> You may prefer to set the textSearchEnabled parameter in the
>   [configuration file](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

I tried to specify this in the configuration file like this:

```
textSearchEnabled=true
```

But it didnt work. Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

Comment: For anybody interested, it is specified in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#setParameter

Comment: Mongos documentation aka "specification" is quite unclear about the syntax. Without the example above I wouldn't have known how the correct syntax.

Comment: Btw. mongo doc states also "You can set multiple setParameter fields." but again, the syntax is unclear. It could be "setParameter=a=1,b=2,c=3" or "setParameter=a=1,setParameter=b=2,setParameter=c=3" or still other variations. The doc really sucks without examples or a clear definition i.e. BNF or something alike.